# How can I capture the id of div in a toggle box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the jQuery toggle feature to create a box with three items. When the user selects one of the options the box should show the price of the option in the total box at the bottom of page and add the cost associated with the checkboxes in the content area of the selected box that are checked.
I am attempting to do this in a php form which has a toggle box modified from this site:

```
<div class="toggle-box">
  <div id="opt1" class="toggle-title">"Snorkel and Serve" Trek in the Florida Keys ($395).</div>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <input id="opt1_1" name="opt1_1" type="checkbox" value="0- I will arrive to campus by 8:00 a.m. on June 25, 2013 ready for departure for the Florida Keys." />
    <label id="opt1_1_label" for="opt1_1" class="normal">I will arrive to campus by 8:00 a.m. on June 25, 2013 ready for departure for the Florida Keys. (No Additional Cost)</label><br /><br />
  </div>
  <div id="opt2" class="toggle-title">Toggle 2</div>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p>Ut orci lorem, malesuada sed rhoncus quis, dignissim eget erat. Sed accumsan lorem sed libero posuere vitae blandit mi varius. Vestibulum eu dui leo, eget molestie quam. Integer non velit arcu, non tempor nulla.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="opt3" class="toggle-title">Toggle 3</div>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <p>Ut orci lorem, malesuada sed rhoncus quis, dignissim eget erat. Sed accumsan lorem sed libero posuere vitae blandit mi varius. Vestibulum eu dui leo, eget molestie quam. Integer non velit arcu, non tempor nulla.</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

When a Title is selected, how can I capture the id of the selected title box?

I'm using the id for the calculate functions below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-content").hide();
    $(".toggle-title").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toggle-content").slideToggle("normal");
        $("#optionselected").val($(this).prop("id"));
        $("#toggle-box input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
        calculate( );
    });
});
$("#toggle-title div").click(function() {
    console.log("click function");
    $("#optionselected").val($(this).prop("id"));
    $("#toggle-box input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
    calculate();
});
function calculate() {
    console.log("balance : " + balance.value);
    var subtotal = 0;
    var optid = $("#optionselected").val();
    var opt1_baseprice = new String($("#opt1").text());
    var opt2_baseprice = new String($("#opt2").text());
    var opt3_baseprice = new String($("#opt3").text());
    opt1_baseprice = opt1_baseprice.substr($("#opt1").text().indexOf("$") + 1, 3);
    opt2_baseprice = opt2_baseprice.substr($("#opt2").text().indexOf("$") + 1, 3);
    opt3_baseprice = opt3_baseprice.substr($("#opt3").text().indexOf("$") + 1, 3);
    opt1_baseprice = parseFloat(opt1_baseprice);
    opt2_baseprice = parseFloat(opt2_baseprice);
    opt3_baseprice = parseFloat(opt3_baseprice);
    subtotal += (optid == "opt1") ? opt1_baseprice : 0;
    subtotal += (optid == "opt2") ? opt2_baseprice : 0;
    subtotal += (optid == "opt3") ? opt3_baseprice : 0;
    $("#toggle-box input[type='checkbox']").each(function(i) {
        subtotal += ($(this).prop("checked")) ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0;
    });
    $("#balance").val((($("#needbased").val() == "Yes") ? (subtotal - 50) : 0).toFixed(2));
    subtotal = ($("#needbased").val() == "Yes") ? 50 : subtotal;
    $("#amount").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Narrow the code down a bit so it is more relevant. No one wants to search through all of that. If in doubt provide a link to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question - is this what you're trying to do?

> When a Title is selected how can I capture the id of the selected
>   title box.

When a title is selected, you can get the `ID` of the currently selected title by using jQuery's `$(this)`

```
$(".toggle-title").click(function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(ID);
});
```